# Simple jquery sum not working without alert

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code not working for first call if alert is commented..please help.

```
function setvalue(){
//alert('something');

            var sum=0;
            $('.charge').each(function(){
                if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
                    sum += Number(this.value);
                }
            });

            $('#total').val(sum);

        }
```

Comment: The alert is working? please post the HTML?

Comment: When does this `setvalue` function get called? If it's right away, it's possible you are calling it before the page finishes loading.

Comment: please post HTML code

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this method should be called when the page contents have finished loading. This can be achieved as follows:

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
   setvalue();
});
```

alternatively

```
$(document).load(function() {
   setvalue();
});
```